# form.is_valid() always fails

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a very basic form that allows the user to upload a txt file. the function form.is_valid() **always fails** and I don't know what to do. This is my code: (very similar to the example in the django documentation):

**views.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    # title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(1)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        print(2)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(3)
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse('thanks')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

**home.html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    <div class="'chooseFile'">
        <h3>Choose file to attach</h3>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.file }}

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" value="Submit"></button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**url.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from adoptions import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='/success/url/'),
]
```

Comment: I see tha tyou have some print statements in there for debugging purposes, what are you getting for output?  also try printing the form to see what you received as input.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you just use a string?

Comment: `form.errors` will not be populated until `form.is_valid()` is run. You are currently printing it before running `is_valid()`. Check what `form.errors` contains *after* you call `is_valid()`, and that will tell you why it's failing to validate.